# Remove underlines from feature files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, cucumber, editor

How do I remove underlines from feature files in IntelliJ, indicating typos?

Note, I'm not talking about underlined variables, but Cucumber .feature files not written in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add them into .idea/dictionaries

Example:

```
<component name="ProjectDictionaryState">
<dictionary name="yourName">
<words>
<w>yourWord</w>
</words>
</dictionary>
</component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be having plugin: 'Substeps IntelliJ Plugin'; installed in your intellij. Uninstall or disable this plugin in intellig from preferences. And only keep plugin: 'cucumber for java'.